# Python -- extracting data from a file using line split

Tags: python-2.7

first time posting, won't be my last.  Trying to learn Python, having a tough time getting a simple task done.

I have 100 files, each one containing tons of text like follows:

Blah blah blah blah blah blah 
Score 99 12 3 3 3
Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah
Score 11 21 96 4 1
Blah blah
Etc...

For every line beginning with "score" I want to extract the second-to-last element in the list (the 4th item, begining with counting at zero).  I want to then do that for all lines in the file containing "score" and write all of those values to an output file.  The name of the output file needs to be the same as the input file plus some suffix.

I have so far a "for loop" combined with a line split, but really am having a hard time putting it all together.  Not sure how to select only those lines beginning with "score", but I know that once I do that then I set up the split command and then extract element 4 then write to an output file.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks Guys

Comment: post the code you have

Comment: I kindof have two parts....

from sys import argv

script, from_file = argv

filename = open(testfile, r)

for row in range(filename.nrows):
    if filename.row_values(row) == "score"
        print score.row_values(row)


and then 

#filename = open(testfile, r)
#with open('test') as input_file:
#       for line in input_file:
 #              print(line)     

#       column_data = line.split()

#    RMS = column_data[0]

#    print RMS

Comment: lol.... sigh... please edit the original post and add code tags so its readable